# newcommand - conditional execution when parameter empty

Tags: macros, ifthenelse

I have following command definition (it's entry of an entrylist) which works fine:

```
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.2cm}{%
    #2%
    \hfill%
    #3%
    \\#4%
  }\\}
```

Now I have a test case when 4th parameter can be empty. In that case I don't want to dispaly the new line defined before it. I've tried the following approach:

```
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.2cm}{%
    #2%
    \hfill%
    #3%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}{}{\\#4}%
  }\\}
```

but it gives me an error:

```
Undefined control sequence. ^^I{test test2}

Missing number, treated as zero. ^^I{test test2}

Missing = inserted for \ifnum. ^^I{test test2}

Missing number, treated as zero. ^^I{test test2}
```

Could you please help?

Comment: they are not the error messages from TeX but possibly a (misleading) summary from your editor, the full error in the log will show which command is undefined.  As you hav enot provided an example or the full error message it is very hard to help, please add a small test file that makes the error,

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I've just discovered that I forgot to add `\usepackage{xifthen}`, `\isempty` was undefined.

Comment: do you use texstudio?

Comment: Yes, I am using TeXstudio

Comment: sad that I can recognise an editor by the fact that it mangles the error messages, but: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I am not using LaTeX on daily basis, therefore my question was not very well defined. But thanks to you I found that TeXstudio has Log window as well as Log file, and in the second one I found better explanation of my error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to have been solved in the comments but I want to suggest two different approaches.

First, `\newcommand` makes it easy to define commands that have one optional argument, provided that it is the first argument. Using this feature you can rewrite your macro as:

```
\newcommand{\entry}[4][]{%
  #2&\parbox[t]{11.2cm}{%
    #3%
    \hfill%
    #4%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\\#1\fi
  }\\}
```

The `[]` says that by default `#1` is empty. This macro is essentially the same as yours except that I have permuted the parameter numbers. The main difference is in how you use the macro:

```
\entry{second}{third}{fourth}
```

without the optional parameter or, if you want to give the optional paramter:

```
\entry[first]{second}{third}{fourth}
```

The second alternative is to use `\NewDocumentCommand` from the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package. The advantage of `\NewDocumentCommand` is that it lets you put the optional argument where ever you want it, including at the end:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\entry}{ mmmo }{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.2cm}{%
    #2%
    \hfill%
    #3%
    \IfNoValueF{#4}{\\#4}% print #4 when it is given
  }\\}
```

The `mmmo` says that there are three **m**anadtory arguments and one **o**ptional argument. Again, the only real difference to your code is in how the macro is used:

```
\entry{first}{second}{third}% without optional argument
\entry{first}{second}{third}[fourth]% with optional argument
```

Comment: Your answer is worth to mark it as a solution :) I will test it in my code!